# How to associate a user profile with other user profiles?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, user-profile

What is the best way to relate a User Profile with objects of the same class. In my case, both parents are attributes of type User Profile. 
My question is if I create a field for each parent, or create a ManyToMany relationship with User Profile, or the relationship should be with User. 
Both father and mother are members of the system.

My class:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User)
     father = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
     mother = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
```

or:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User)
     father = models.ForeignKey(User)
     mother = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

or:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User)
     parents = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile)
```

or:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User)
     parents = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

**WHAT IS THE BEST WAY?**

Comment: There is no best way, just compromises that you should base on your specific use-case. Do you want to be able to handle e.g. divorced and remarried parents with a `ManyToManyField`, but at the cost of some efficiency and ease of use? Might you want to add other relations later on? Do you need access to the parents `UserProfile` often, or do you just need access to the `User` object? These are all questions that can't be answered without more detailed knowledge of the system you want to design.

Comment: My app is a church management system, where the names of the parishioners and the sacraments performed is recorded. It registers each componet of the family, parents and siblings, who are also part of the system, they also have sacraments. These parishioners may also be catechist, secretaries, etc.

Answer (score -2):

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User)
     father = models.ForeignKey(User)
     mother = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: I think this will raise an error. You should add related_name for all three model fields.

Comment: So what is the best way to handle relationships?

Comment: I meant that is architectonically the best way to do this. Yes, you will have to add related names to the two last fields